# Oracle reserved word - WALLET

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, reserved-words

**WALLET** is in V$RESERVED_WORDS but it it with RESERVED - N value

Can I use WALLET as a new schema name in Oracle 11g database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you?  Yes.

Should you?  Probably not.  Using a reserved word as an identifier is generally a bad idea.  If there is another identifier you can use that would be meaningful, I would strongly suggest using that.